# How can I filter out the "My Computer"-option in a SWT DirectoryDialog?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

in our Eclipse RCP application running on Windows XP we use a DirectoryDialog, in which the user should... ahmm... choose a directory! :D

The problem is: If the user selects the "My Computer"-option (in German Windows "Arbeitsplatz") the Dialog returns null.

The DirectoryDialog provides a method setFilterPath(String path) in which I put the File.pathSeparatorChar (to remain OS-independant).

My suggestion was that if there has to be a file separator in the directory the "My Computer"-option would be ignored cause it is null - for example the "OK"-button would be greyed out or sth. like that... but it is also valid to klick "OK".

Any suggestions from your side? :D

Thanks in advance!

Alex

Comment: `My Computer` is not a directory, so I think it's fine for the `OK` button to be gray.

Comment: +1 this should be the answer, not an comment.

Comment: NOTE 1: setFilterPath sets the initial selection of the dialog and does not filter out anything.
NOTE 2: Pressing "Cancel" in the dialog also results in "null". From what I can tell it's practically imposible to treat "Cancel" and selecting invalid paths differently

Comment: What version of SWT are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`My Computer` is not a directory, so I think it's fine for the `OK` button to be gray.

Comment: The problem is that the OK button is **not** grayed out.

Comment: @drstupid: Now I understand the problem, although it's strange.

Comment: I am using Eclipse RCP Galileo, so I guess 3.5.1! Any suggestions?

Comment: The version of Eclipse is one thing, and the version of SWT is another. What does `SWT.getVersion()` print?